# How to fix Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\Ayuso.android\build-cache\b2c92a1a34e3ead110e3f2338c3550cf7dccb6d4\output\res\values-in\values.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

[image]

Comment: where is `build.gradle`

Comment: how i can fix this? im anoob

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your `values.xml` which reside in `res/values-es/`. The `values.xml` must contain **valid XML** tag. It will give an error if the file is a blank text file. You need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Add your layout here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix it downloading the new version of android studio beta..